# Is a comeagre set closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

In this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set

The complement of a meagre set is a comeagre set or residual set.

I am asking if a comeagre set is still **closed** in the (usually larger) topological space. If no, is there is any examples of that property.

Comment: Hardly ever (if ever).

Comment: It might help to realize that $\mathbb R$ can be expressed as the disjoint union of a meager set and a Lebesgue measure zero set (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494705/13130)), and thus a co-meager set can have Lebesgue measure zero (equivalently, a meager set can be such that its intersection with every open interval has Lebesgue measure equal to the length of that interval). In fact, in $\mathbb R$ a co-meager set can be MUCH smaller, having Hausdorff dimension zero (see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm2/cm215.pdf) for stronger results in more general spaces).

Answer (score 2):

The topological spaces $X$ where the only closed comeagre subset is $X$ itself are called *Baire spaces*. It is a very large class of spaces which includes all locally compact Hausdorff spaces and all complete metric spaces.

On the other hand, in $\Bbb Q$ all subsets are (co)meagre.

**Added:** Also, notice that a topological space has some non-closed comeagre subset if and only if it isn't discrete. In fact, let $x\in X$ be a non-open point. Then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is comeagre and non-closed. On the other hand, if $X$ is discrete then $X$ is the only comeagre subset of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is comeagre in $\mathbb R$, but it is *not* a closed subset.